# Execute JUnit tests inside Docker container

Tags: java, docker, junit

I would like to build a test environment with Docker, where I can remotely send JUnit test classes (including the code that is tested), execute the tests and retrieve the results.

I found some articles which explained how to use docker for testing databaseconntection/writing inside a redis, but not how i can simple let my tests perform on docker and retrieve the results.

Do you have any recommendations how You would actually achieve this?
I don't know much about Jenkins, but would this might solve my problem?
Is there any good framework outside for this?

Answer (score 1):

One way I found that works (using Gradle) is as follows. I know you are specifically referencing JUnit as your testing framework, but I actually think something similar to this could work.

Dockerfile (I called mine `Dockerfile.UnitTests`):

```
FROM gradle:jdk8 AS test-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN gradle clean
RUN gradle test

FROM scratch AS export-stage
COPY --from=test-stage /app/build/reports/tests/test/* /
```

I then run this with (in Gitbash on Windows 10):

```sh
> DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -f Dockerfile.UnitTests --output type=tar,dest=UnitTests.tar .
```

This results in a tar file containing the test results displayed in an html file.

I executed the above in a Gitlab CI/CD pipeline and then sent the results to a web API for analysis.

#### A couple of assumptions:

1. My project is set up for Gradle builds so I have the structure from the root of my project `src/test/java/groupname/projectname/testfile.java`
2. I am working in Windows 10 targeting Linux containers and using Gitbash.

Answer (score 0):

In a dockerfile, checkout your code and do a "maven test" command, redirect the result in a file that is on a mounted directory.
Each time you build the dockerfile, you do a unit test on your project.

With docker you also have a "docker test" command. I dont know if there is a plugin to use it on jenkins.